# CollectionView doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view, but delegate and data source methods are not getting called.  Then I added this lines to the `viewdidload()` method

`wordsCollection.dataSource = self
 wordsCollection.delegate = self`

How can I avoid using this explicit asigning? And why my collectionView is being loaded too long?

Comment: @ Alexander Can you please share some code

Comment: you can assign delegate and data source in stroyboard also.

Comment: @Coder, what code are you interested in? It's just very general Collection View code stuff.
And why it loads so long?

Comment: @Alexander CollectionView's loading time depends on your code and amount of data you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set datasource and delegate of collection view in interface build too.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign datasource and delegate of collectionview from storyboard too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set **dataSource** and **delegate** from **Collection View** to **View Controller** in your designed storyboard

[image: dataSource and delegate set from storyboard]

Comment: Well, thanks, it's clear. And why it loads too long?

Comment: you can also check your image size that you set in collection view cell . It may be a reason.